# How to remove the duplicate values from the Object

Tags: javascript, object, filter

I have an object below.

```
object1 = {name: "tony, tony", city: "Reno, Reno", country: "Canada, Canada"}
```

I want to remove the duplicate values in the object1 and return as follows.

```
 filteredObject = {name: "tony",city: "Reno", country: "Canada"}
```

Is there any good way to achieve this?

Comment: It's possible of course, but I'm wondering where you're getting the original object from? If possible, you should rather fix what leads to object1 looking like that in the first place.

Comment: You are right. I should do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `for..in` loop to iterate through object. And then `split()` each of the the value and remove duplicate using **[Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)** and **[Spread Synatax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)** and `join()`

```js
const obj = object1 = {name: "tony, tony", city: "Reno, Reno", country: "Canada, Canada"};
const filteredObj ={};
for(let key in obj){
 filteredObj[key] = [... new Set(obj[key].split(', '))].join(', ');
}
console.log(filteredObj)
```

Comment: Thank you. It is pretty new to me and still trying to understand the login behind it. It works.

Answer (score 2):

## Explanation

You can use the `map` and `reduce` functions to manipulate your object keys. In order to remove duplications, you can use a *temporary dictionary* that will hold your keys. The individual values in the string can be found using `str.split(', ')`. It looks something like this

## Code

```js
// Reno, Reno, Toronto => Reno, Toronto    
const removeDupsFromString = (s) => {
  const dict = s.split(', ').reduce((acc, curr) => {
    acc[curr] = true;
    return acc;
  }, {});

  return Object.keys(dict).join(', ');
}

const removeDupsFromObject = (obj) => Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, key) => {
  acc[key] = removeDupsFromString(obj[key]);
  return acc;
}, {});

const obj = {
  name: "Tony, Tony, Stark",
  city: "Reno, Reno",
  country: "Canada, Canada"
};

console.log(removeDupsFromObject(obj));
```

## Note

This does not keep the words in order though, `Tony, Tony, Stark` might produce either `Tony, Stark` or `Stark, Tony`, since it uses `Object.keys`

Comment: This works for the OPs example, but for yours it would return a name of either `'Tony, Stark'` or `'Stark, Tony'` non-deterministicaly, since it uses an object and object keys are unordered. Object.keys might not return them in the order encountered in the string.

Comment: Yes you're right, it doesn't preserve the order of words. I included your note in the answer

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to to accumulate the result after removing the duplicate entries from the object values.

[`Object#entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) will give an array of the [key,value] pairs in the object as an array.

The `reduce` will act on the that array and accumulate it into a new object by only taking the unique value. The `replace(/\s+/g, '')` would remove all white spaces otherwise the set won't treat the words as unique (Considering the case when the space could be either before or after the comma ",").

```js
const object1 = {name: "tony, tony", city: "Reno, Reno", country: "Canada, Canada", foo: "foo, foo, bar", baz: "baz ,bar ,bar"};
//Notice the last entry in this object where space is before the comma
const obj = Object.entries(object1).reduce((acc, ele) => {
   acc[ele[0]] = [...new Set(ele[1].replace(/\s+/g, '').split(","))].join(",");
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: This does not remove duplicates like OP asked. It only gets the first word

Comment: @molamk right, good observation. I edited it to only include the unique elements.

Comment: Thank you. Actually this was really helpful. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

Using `object.keys` and  `forEach` and `Set`

```js
let object1 = {name: "tony, tony, stark, start, stark", city: "Reno, Reno", country: "Canada, Canada"}

let filteredObject = {}

Object.keys(object1).forEach(e=>{
  filteredObject[e] = [...new Set(object1[e].split(', '))].join(', ')
})


console.log(filteredObject)
```

Comment: This does not remove duplicates. It only gets the first word. `tony, hello` will be transformed into "tony" even if there is no duplication

Comment: @molamk thanks for pointing out. added set to answer for handling duplicates

Comment: Thank you. I am trying this one right now and it works.